# T-SQL CTE Question (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Why does the following query work, when there is no column named Agentid in the "NewAccounts"-CTE?

```
WITH 
NewAccounts AS (
    SELECT 3 as Newaccountid
),
MovedAUM AS (
    SELECT 1 AS Agentid, 2 as Col2
)
SELECT * FROM MovedAUM WHERE agentid IN (SELECT Agentid FROM NewAccounts)
```

The following, modified query returns the error message as expected:

```
WITH 
NewAccounts AS (
    SELECT 3 AS newaccountid
)
SELECT Agentid FROM NewAccounts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one works because `MovedAUM` is in scope within the nested `SELECT`.  It is actually returning `MovedAUM.AgentId` for each row in `NewAccounts`.  In other words the `WHERE` clause is doing nothing - it's equivalent to `WHERE 1 = 1`.

This slightly modified version will fail:

```
WITH  
NewAccounts AS ( 
    SELECT 3 as Newaccountid 
), 
MovedAUM AS ( 
    SELECT 1 AS Agentid, 2 as Col2 
) 
SELECT * FROM MovedAUM WHERE agentid IN
    (SELECT NewAccounts.Agentid FROM NewAccounts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing explicit join in that with

```
SELECT * FROM TAB1, TAB2
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server knows, it has the Agentid columns and can use it, however it is not what you want, don't use IN, use EXISTS it will prevent this

```
WITH 
NewAccounts AS (
    SELECT 3 as Newaccountid
),
MovedAUM AS (
    SELECT 1 AS Agentid, 2 as Col2
)
SELECT * FROM MovedAUM WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                              FROM NewAccounts 
                              where NewAccounts.Agentid = MovedAUM.agentid )
```

See also here: http://sqlservercode.blogspot.com/2007/04/you-should-never-use-in-in-sql-to-join.html